# How do you open Apt links in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, firefox

I'm trying to download an Apt file but I don't know how to. I'm using Firefox too.

Comment: It is just a file, you download it just like any other. BTW, are you sure you cannot get it from the official repositories?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Associate apt links in firefox with `/usr/bin/software-center`

Just tried it for a playdeb.net link and it brings it up for you.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a lighter alternative to Ubuntu Software Center, that handles Apt links, you can use [AptURL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL), that needs to be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install apturl
```

Then, you can associate apt links in Firefox with /usr/bin/apturl, as described in screenshot below.

[image: Selecting AptURL to apt links]

Comment: What to do if you want to download that file, not open it with software center?

Comment: You cannot "download that file", because an apt link does not point to a phisical file, but refer only to a package name. So the only way is to process the apt link in a package manager, that will search and download the referred package.

Comment: Can't we get location of that referred package, so that we can download it?

Comment: not from the link itself.. only the package manager knows the repository location

Comment: It's better to install the graphic version: `apturl-gtk`.