# Are there alternatives to software center?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center, alternative

Are there any GUI alternatives to the Ubuntu Software Center with

- Fast application loading/Low startup time
- Fast search
- Low weight/size
- Application purchase facility

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternative to the Ubuntu Software Center named `appgrid`. It's a very lightweight application center for Ubuntu and it will let you purchase applications too. You can install it in Ubuntu with these following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appgrid/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install appgrid
```

It was only a 100KB download for me.

Comparison between `appgrid` and Ubuntu Software Center:

```
Feature                                                | appgrid  | Ubuntu Software Center
-------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------------------
Programming language                                   | Python 3 | Python 2
Warm start to home screen                              | 2.7s     | 20s
Warm start to details screen (eg opening an apt: link) | 2.3s     | 30s
Full database build                                    | 58s      | 6min24
Initial database size                                  | 36.7MB   | 96.5MB
Memory usage after startup to home screen              | 20MB     | 53.6MB
Lines of code (including tests)                        | 5900     | 56960
```

You can sign in with Ubuntu One ID also:

[image: Ubuntu One sign in screenshot]

[image: appgrid screenshot]

Comment: @Flimm Thats really looking nice my friend,:) . How did you do that ?

Comment: I think it was with this website [here](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html). Use tabs to create a new column. Make sure to bookmark it!

Comment: @minerz029: I actually used a plug-in for Vim called Tabular, but that website looks useful, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I have tried upgrading and updating my install of Ubuntu 16.04. I have no PPA's in my sources list, and I just can't make Ubuntu Software work. Since AppGrid is so small I decided to try it out, and it works great!

Answer (score 28):

You can use `synaptic`  , a front-end for `apt-get`.

Comment: This is not application store - `synaptic` is a GUI package manager which allows you search and install packages from public repositories. Review this article for more details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository

Answer (score 17):

Yes. Try the Lubuntu Software Center. It is very fast and light-weight.

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center`

[image]

Comment: Best option in the list. 
Simple and usable. 
It allows to remove lot of "leftover" apps, including unity and gnome built-in software. (but pay attention to what you're removing!)

Answer (score 14):

I noticed that [deepin software-center](http://www.linuxdeepin.com/feature) is not on this list...

[image: deepin-screenshot-1]

[image: deepin-screenshot-2]

[image: deepin-screenshot-3]

**Features**:

- There is a regularly updated list of featured applications on the
  home page. The list of recommendations are produced based on user
  ratings.
- The Software Repository gives you a handy way to choose and install
  desired applications with just one click. With a powerful
  multi-threaded download back-end, they are available to you for fast
  download, limited only by your network connection.
- Update manager helps you make sure your operating system has the
  latest and greatest software installed. All the updates are available
  for free!
- Uninstalling applications that you no longer need gives you an
  opportunity to have a cleaner working environment.
- Comes with 9 pre-installed colorful skins, so you can select one that
  brightens your day!
- Cleanup cached packages to gain more space
- Open download location and refresh application list
- We have added official Ubuntu sources for fast downloads

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/deepin-sc
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install deepin-software-center
> ```

**Reference**:

- [Linux Deepin - Features](http://www.linuxdeepin.com/feature)

Answer (score 13):

You can try to familiarize yourself with the command lines:
Searching:

```
apt-cache search wesnoth
```

This will often yield many results, so it is useful to pipe eg to less or to use grep to search further:

```
apt-cache search wesnoth |less
```

Search in all descriptions for FTP, show only the matches which have FTP in the package description

```
apt-cache search FTP |grep FTP |less
```

Installing:

```
sudo apt-get install wesnoth
```

Removing:

```
sudo apt-get remove wesnoth
```

Comment: -1. The user specifically asks for GUI solutions.

Comment: @landroni +1. sometimes users need to be educated and do not know what they want :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is Muon Software Center (`muon-installer`), default Kubuntu software manager.

You can install it in Ubuntu, but it'll probably have a lot of Qt and KDE dependencies.

I recommend you `aptitude`, it's similar to `apt-get` but it has a very easy to use CLI.

You can always use `synaptic`, it's fairly easy to use and very powerful.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo aptitude` is my personal favorite, used in the command line, very quick response on my 500mhz command line system.

```
sudo aptitude
```

You can also do it without `sudo` or root, but you can only view packages installed and search for packages.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed nobody mentioned `gnome-software`
[image: <code>gnome-software</code>]

It will replace `software-center` in 16.04, but I quite like `software-center` itself.

Comment: It is available on 14.04 as well

Comment: I researched in repo and online but couldn't find it. Then, I found [this discussion](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/gnome-software-centre-for-16-04-is-ready-for-testing/3470) on Ubuntu MATE forum, one user quoted that "Should have mentioned, this is for 16.04 only. I'm not aware if there's plans to backport it to 14.04." The user who added testing PPA to 14.04 had errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to search for Ubuntu applications in the Ubuntu official repositories, you can browse the official "Apps" website: https://apps.ubuntu.com/

Here you can also quicly see screenshots and reviews for every app.

To install an app, you can just click the "Available in the Software Center" button in app detail page, using the "apt:" protocol.

Here you can find info about apt links:

- [How do you open Apt links in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317617/how-do-you-open-apt-links-in-ubuntu)
- [Can I use other than Ubuntu Software Center to open apt links?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183517/can-i-use-other-ways-than-ubuntu-software-center-to-open-apt-links/183536)

Or you can just install the found package with `synaptic` or directly with command line `sudo apt-get install <name>`, as reported in other answers.

Comment: `apps.ubuntu.com` has been replaced by `snapcraft.io` and only offers snap apps. So it is not useful for people who use Ubuntu without snaps

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

[Appnr : A web based software center](http://appnr.com/)

This is a website which primarily uses the functionality of apt-url to install apps on Ubuntu.

More details find here : [How to Download??](http://www.tricksfind.in/2013/08/appnr-alternative-of-ubuntu-software.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled online search on Unity, your able to search for an app in the Unity App scope, under « More Suggestions ». Right click on the app and you'll see the description (aka Preview mode). And you've the ability to install the app from here, very quickly

Answer (score 1):

You can use aptitude (if it counts). It should be pre-installed with your system but otherwise you can install it using apt-get :

```
apt-get install aptitude
```

And then it should be fine.

Note: I didn't do any research before writing this answer, so some parts can be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `mintinstall`, avaliable from the Linux Mint repos

See [How to add Linuxmint repositories to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507707/how-to-add-linuxmint-repositories-to-ubuntu)

Comment: As Linux Mint is off-topic here, I am downvoting this answer as it does not provide an alternative to the **Ubuntu** software center, equipped with access to the official **Ubuntu** repositories.

Comment: The Mnt package manager can access the Ubuntu repos and it is an alternative fully compatible with Ubuntu.

Comment: Then, if you edit your question to walk to the user through the installation and usage of `mintinstall`, I will reverse my downvote.

Comment: i'v made a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/matan-h/bd432416378c2093e5d4182f1fea5151) that explains how to install `mintinstall` store on ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

there is [bauh](https://github.com/vinifmor/bauh) store:

Graphical user interface for managing your Linux applications. Supports AppImage, Debian packages, Flatpak, Snap and native Web applications

to install read the [installation guide](https://github.com/vinifmor/bauh#installation)

[image: panel image from github]

Answer (score 0):

There is `gnome-packagekit` as well.  It is easy to install multiple apps at once with the checkboxes. If you have used `gnome-app-install` (Add/Remove) on version prior to 9.10, it works it pretty much the same way.