# The Software Center won't start anymore, how to fix it?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center

I have been using Ubuntu 13.04 for last 2 months. It was working properly but suddenly the Ubuntu Software Center has started hanging. Now it doesn't open. And every time I try to open it, I have to force quit it. So that I am not able to install the software that I need. What do I do?

Answer (score 10):

#### Make sure `software-center` is not running.

First make sure the Software Center (process name `software-center`) is not running. Depending on how you've been forcing it to quit, a `software-center` process may or may not still be running in the background.

*If you know how to make sure a process isn't running, you can skip the rest of this section.*

You can use the GNOME System Monitor for this (type *system monitor* in the Unity dash and an icon for GNOME System Monitor will appear).

Or you can use [`killall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/killall.1.html) from the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
killall software-center
```

Run it again and you should get:

```
software-center: no process found
```

If you don't see that, it's still running. In that case, run:

```
killall -KILL software-center
```

(Running that again will, in the same way, determine if it succeeeded)

The Software Center is not ordinarily run as root: instead, it uses polkit to perform specific actions as root. But if it is running as root, then you'll have to put `sudo`  before a `killall` command for it to succeed.

#### Clear out both user-specific and systemwide configuration files and reinstall USC.

Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) if you don't already have one open. Run these commands to remove user-specific configuration files:

```
cd ~/.config
mv software-center software-center.old
```

(This actually moves the configuration rather than deleting it, but it prevents it from being used. It's unlikely you'll need to restore it, but there's no major disadvantage.)

Then *reinstall* the Software Center, removing systemwide configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center
```

Some errors that could interfere with the Software Center starting or working properly could also keep those commands from working. In particular, if you see an error that says `Unable to lock the administration directory`, check out the answers here:

- [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem)

Then try running the Software Center again.

#### If that doesn't work...

...then more information will be needed. Run the Software Center itself in the Terminal:

```
software-center
```

That may reveal messages (errors or otherwise) that would help solve the problem. You can edit your question to include all the text from the Terminal.

*(Other people with this problem should create or edit their own questions, of course.)*

One possible cause of this problem might be if [polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) is not running, or not working properly. If you don't see any helpful messages when you run `software-center` in the Terminal, you might try running it as root:

```
gksudo software-center
```

If you don't have the `gksudo` command, you can install it (it's provided by the [gksu [image: Install gksu]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gksu) package), or use `sudo -H` instead of `gksudo`.

If that doesn't work *and you need a workaround to install software until the problem iss solved*, see:

- [Are there alternatives to software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339697/are-there-alternatives-to-software-center)

In particular, [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) works very differently from the Software Center and is quite likely to work even when the Software Center does not. Synaptic does not provide the means to install paid apps, though.

Comment: How can I fix polkit not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Based on something I read on another forum, I changed my dock icons and software center came back.

---

Yes, I know that sounds completely bonkers, but the only thing I've done since it stopped working was to change the icons in my dock from "elementary" to "default" and so after banging on this problem for an hour (updating everything, cleaning up everything, clearing sysconfigs, uninstalling/re-installing software-center and pretty much everything that touches it, threadkilling, re-booting, running software-center in root... etc.)

At wit's end, I changed the icons &

...presto chango, up comes software center as if nothing was ever wrong.

The good news is that my system is now clean and shiny and completely up-to-date.

Lol.

Answer (score 0):

This article should help you fix the issue.
http://www.crappy3.com/fix-ubuntu-software-center-doesnt-start-issue/

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.