# can't open software-center and software & updates

Tags: updates, software-center, python, gtk

This is the error i'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 373, in __init__
    self.cache, self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/globalpane.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.back_forward.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 313, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 165, in __getattr__
    setattr(wrapper, value_name, wrapper(value_info.get_value()))
ValueError: invalid enum value: 4
```

Comment: You can check this solution  ---   http://askubuntu.com/questions/342654/the-software-center-wont-start-anymore-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

The package that offends you is `python-gi`, may be it is misconfigured. Reinstall it from command line

```
sudo apt-get purge python-gi
sudo apt-get install python-gi
```

Just in case, make sure it does not try to delete anything else, (it will ask if it wants to). You may try in with `software-center` too.