# How to add Linuxmint repositories to Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, repository, mint

I want to add some Linuxmint packages to be installed in Ubuntu 14.04LTS. How can one add the Linuxmint (any version) repositories to ubuntu (any version) ?

Comment: What packages are you looking for specifically? If it is Cinnamon and Nemo you want, they are in a PPA (which is safer than adding Mint repos).

Comment: @RolandiXor I am not specifically looking for one package but some good functionality to add to my Ubuntu box from some other repositories. Such like Mint-X Gtk3+ themes and some Mate Desktop environment settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the Linux Mint LTS release (Qiana or Mint 17) repositories to my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by running the following commands through the terminal:

1. Add the repository

```bsh
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list'
```

2. Now run an update to retrieve information about what packages are available:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
```

```
You'll see an error in the update highlighting that public key is not available for the Linux Mint repository just added:
```

> `GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com qiana Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <em>&ltSome scramble encryption number&gt</em>`

3. To avoid this, run another command to download the Linux Mint keyring:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring
   ```

   It will ask your permission to download, say yes.
4. Once downloaded, update your package database again:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you'll see that the update is successful and without any error.

Once updated, we are ready to install any packages from linuxmint repositories.

Comment: BTW - Is it safe to use mint packages in ubuntu? mintbackup for example? would it work ok?